# How can I tell my dd-wrt router to use someone's Amazon Affiliates link when I point my browser to amazon.com?

Tags: dd-wrt, redirection

Here's what I'd like to do. Instead of a one-time donation to one of my favorite free tools (junecloud.com) I'd like to do what they suggest [here](http://junecloud.com/software/donate/) and use their Amazon Affiliates link to do all my Amazon shopping. I shop at amazon once or twice a week, so this is a great way to let them earn lots of long-term cash without me dropping a dime.

My thought was to go into my dd-wrt enabled router and tell it, "any time I go to amazon.com on any computer in the house, please go to [http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?link_code=ur2&tag=junecloud-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&location=%2F](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?link_code=ur2&tag=junecloud-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&location=/) instead. (That URL simply redirects me to amazon.com but every purchase I make during that session is credited to JuneCloud.)

Once logged into dd-wrt, I went to Services > Services > DNSMasq but I'm not really sure how to get it to work from there, or if it's even possible. I know I can redirect IP addresses, but I'm looking to redirect someone on my network from amazon.com to the special amazon affiliate code link.

Hope that's clear. Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 2):

A couple hack-arounds...

If everyone in your home uses Chrome, you can install [Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh) or search for similar extensions.

A more transparent solution would be to run a web server such as [Apache](https://www.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) on your local machine, then use the IP of your server in the `DNSMasq` section of DD-WRT. On the index.html page of your server you could redirect the user to http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?link_code=ur2&tag=junecloud-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&location=%2F with HTML or PHP.

PHP:

```
 <?php

   header( 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?link_code=ur2&tag=junecloud-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&location=%2F' ) ;

 ?>
```

HTML:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?link_code=ur2&tag=junecloud-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&location=%2F">
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few possibilities, but nothing that would likely fit inside a home router running DD-WRT.

Your best solution is probably just to visit each computer in the house and create a bookmark.